# Cannot find linux-headers-4.3.0-kali-amd64

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, vmware

I'm trying to install the VMware tools in a VMPlayer VM but in a certain point of the installation I need to set the linux-headers path. So I go and try to install it with this command:

```
apt-get install gcc make linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Then I get the error:

```
Couldnt find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali-amd64'
```

My **sources.list** file has these sources:

```
 deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
 deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free

 deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main contrib non-free
 deb http://http.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
 deb http://http.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

I already did and `apt-get update` before trying to install the headers. What can I do to download it?

Answer (score 11):

I would upgrade the kernel release version itself instead of trying to install the Linux kernel headers for the old version (4.3.0) of the kernel. Perform the following step after updating the Kali `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with the latest version of the [Kali rolling repository](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories):

```
sudo apt-get update # this pulls the latest packages list from the kali sources repo
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade # when installing this, you would see the latest kernel 
                        # image in the list of packages to be installed,something
                        # like" linux-image-4.5.0-kali1-amd64"
reboot # MOST IMPORTANT STEP! make sure you reboot the machine via this cmd OR 
                        # shutdown, restart forcefully after completing prev cmds
uname -r # check that the kernel release has updated
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you probably meet this problem that lack of linux headers when you install the VMware Tools.

In fact, there's new way to solve the issue in official Kali website: http://docs.kali.org/general-use/install-vmware-tools-kali-guest.

As the tutorial says, if your version of VMware is after Sept 2015, you can use the following code to install it:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop fuse
reboot
```

Then, you may find you can use the VMware Tools and with the linux-headers updating.

Answer (score 3):

To get the required information about the available `linux-headers` , run the following command :

```
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

You will not see the `linux-headers-4.3.0-kali-amd64` because the kali repo is updated , some old packages versions will be removed and the newest will take its place.

You should found the latest `linux-image` :

```
apt-cache search linux-image
```

Install it e,g:

```
apt-get install linux-image-4.9.0-kali4-amd64
```

Reboot your system and install the appropriate  `linux-headers` package :

```
apt-get install linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-amd64
```

The `linux-image` and `linux-headers` packages should have the same version.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information @GAD3R. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem.

This is what I did:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

Then when I went to install the headers, it finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the source list not correct, you could using the rolling-up source like, deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib, and at same time remove all of other items in the source list.

Answer (score 0):

First try to install dkms package by using **apt-get install dkms** after that try to update header by command apt-get -y upgrade 
May be that can solve header.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate solution - one can attempt to manually install the older packages without upgrading the kernel. It is a bit elaborate, but I have tried this with Kali Linux 2016.2 i386, and the following kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux hacker 4.6.0-kali1-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) i686 GNU/Linux
```

I searched for linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686-pae online, and found that .deb packages for the linux kernel headers are located [here](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/) via Google search. Then, I installed the following packages (linux-headers and its dependencies) for i386 - you can install the appropriate versions based on your architecture:

```
$ dpkg -i linux-kbuild-4.6_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
$ dpkg -i linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
$ dpkg -i linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-i386_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
$ dpkg -i linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686-pae_4.6.4-1kali1_i386.deb
```

After installation, just reboot and the kernel headers should be available.

```
$ reboot
```