# VirtualBox installation problem and no WiFi connectivity on Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, network-interface

I was trying to install VirtualBox in Kali Linux but somehow ended up screwing up whole system two times.

What I did :

1. Updated the repository to the following:

   deb http:// http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
      deb http:// old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
2. `apt update && apt -y dist-upgrade`
3. `apt-get install virtualbox`

After this I opened virtualbox from the terminal. However it opened and gave error that I need to install `virtualbox-dkms`.
It installed successfully (no errors) but when I tried to open virtualbox there was same error as mentioned above. So, I remembered something, while I was installing `dkms` it showed few line:
which stated `COULDN'T FIND LINUX HEADERS`. But as far I have searched `dist-upgrade` should have upgraded the kernel headers. Isn't it? So, next I ran

4. Next

   ```
   apt-get install gcc
   make linux-headers-$(uname -r)
   ```

   Error:

   ```
   Couldnt find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali-amd64
   ```

I found a similar post ([Cannot find linux-headers-4.3.0-kali-amd64](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266871/cannot-find-linux-headers-4-3-0-kali-amd64)) and tried the solutions presented there but it was of no help. I was still searching web for some solution, one post suggested that I should run `apt -y install open-vm-tools-desktop fuse`. I am so dumb, without doing any further research about it. I simply ran it and did a reboot. After that Kali was not able to find any WiFi network connection. So I checked `ifconfig` but it did not have any `wlan0`, however `eth0` and local host is still there.

My Problems :

1. When I try to open VirtualBox it gives error.
2. Not able to connect to the internet via WiFi after running `apt -y install open-vm-tools-desktop fuse`

   After this I searched a little bit more and found the following link: http://docs.kali.org/general-use/install-vmware-tools-kali-guest. I guess from heading only it is clear that it was for Kali Guest.

Is there any way to revert back, so Linux could connect to web.
How do I fix VirtualBox?
I am sure secure boot is off and virtualization is enabled.

1:

After running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`
Output-
 `08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci`

2:

As suggested to Check the available kernels :

`apt-cache search linux-image`

Install the latest linux-image and the linux-headers:

`apt-get install linux-image-X.Y...`
`apt-get install linux-headers-X.Y...`

I installed the top two search result and did a reboot and to my shock again WiFi connection was gone again(it was a fresh install). How can it be happening? Did something went wrong while installng linux-image? but when I run `uname -r` is shows `4.8.0` earlier it was `4.6.0`

Comment: welcome to U&L please edit by adding the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install the `linux-headers` you should upgrade your kernel version.

Check the available kernels :

```
apt-cache search linux-image
```

Install the latest `linux-image` and the `linux-headers`:

```
apt-get install linux-image-X.Y...
apt-get install linux-headers-X.Y...
```

Reboot and run : `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` to get the required information about your wifi card and install the needed driver.

**Edit**

To install the RT3290 wifi driver run:

```
apt-get install firmware-ralink
```

Comment: The thing is I can connect to web via WiFi only. I do not have broadband connection. So should I install it again? I already have kali-linux-2016.2-amd64

Comment: You need an internet connction to upgrade your kernel and installing the wifi driver

Comment: as you said I installed the top two search result and did a reboot and to my shock again WiFi connection was gone (it was a fresh install). How can it be happening? Did something went wrong while installng linux-image? but when I run `uname -r` is shows `4.8.0` earlier it was `4.6.0`